# Create post entity to crm

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am getting unexpected error while trying to create post in Dynamics CRM. Below is the code:

```
Entity objEntity = new Entity("post");  

objEntity["regardingobjectid"] = IncidentID;
objEntity["text"] = URLs;
objEntity["source"] =  new OptionSetValue(2);
objEntity["type"] = new OptionSetValue(4);

Guid newPostID =  lOrgService.Create(objEntity);
```

Please suggest what could be the problem.

Comment: Please include the error in your question

Comment: Needs some clarification: is it 4.0 or 2011 (retag the question appropriately) ? Which rollup version ? What's the error ? Is the code in a plugin, custom wf activity or external program ?

Answer (score 4):

It could be a multitude of things, which is hard to pinpoint based on the small amount of code you have submitted, but my best guess is that `IncidentID` is a GUID, where `regardingobjectid` should be an `EntityReference`.

Try replacing:

`objEntity["regardingobjectid"] = IncidentID;`

with

`objEntity["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference("incident", IncidentID);`